# Am I missing something, or is this code nonsensical?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce, .net-1.1, format-string

While exploring the dank catacombs and dusty dungeons of our legacy code, I came across this:

```
FormatString formatString = new FormatString();
if (formatString.containsAlpha(UPCE) != -1) 
{
    UPCLen = 11;
}
```

Am I missing something, or is my reaction to this, namely: How can formatString contain anything? Nothing has been assigned to it...It will *always* be **-1**, assuming that indicates 'not found'" correct?

### UPDATE

In answer to the general confusion evident in the comments, I thought FormatString was some haywire stone ages .NET thing (this project uses .NET 1.1), but you're right - this is a homegrown class. Here is the constructor:

```
public FormatString()
{
}
```

...and the containsAlpha() method:

```
public int containsAlpha(string strToCheck)
{
    const string ALPHA_CHARS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    try
    {
        char[] tmpCharArry = ALPHA_CHARS.ToCharArray();
        return strToCheck.ToLower().IndexOfAny(tmpCharArry);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Duckbill.ExceptionHandler(ex, "FormatString.containsAlpha");
        return 0; // not -1?
    }
}
```

Now I ask you: Is "FormatString" a wrong-headed name for this class, or what? I found it very misleading (obviously).

Comment: What _is_ `FormatString` at all?

Comment: What's a `FormatString`? The constructor could be doing anything for all we know.

Comment: Tim's right, `FormatString` is not part of the CLR. Perhaps it is has some nasty critters living inside it.

Comment: Try right-clicking on `FormatString` and select `Go To Definition`.  See where it goes.

Comment: FormatString may have a value on instantiation, you will have to look at the source code, check out the new constructor to see what it does. Looks like you got a company internal business object, FormatString is not part of the .NET Framework

Comment: I'm assuming it's a helper class that checks whether its passed argument contains Alphas. It's odd that it's not static, but, ...

Comment: This is what you get when you have savvy junior consultants offhandedly telling stone-age autodidacts to organize their string formatting functions in a separate class, while insisting that it should not be static because that's how they learned it in school, completely ignoring the part where the project doesn't use any kind of dependency injection.

Comment: I'm not sure who is meant to be who here, but the "stone-age autodidact" does kind of fit me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all we know, it could be something like this:

```
public class FormatString
{
    public int containsAlpha(object foo)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

That would satisfy the example you showed.  It doesn't even need a constructor definition.

You should right-click and "go to definition" to find out what it really does.

**UPDATE**

Based on your updated details, If you could use a newer .NET Framework, I'd say you could replace the entire function with this:

```
using System.Linq;

public static bool ContainsAlpha(string s)
{
    return s != null && s.Any(Char.IsLetter);
}
```

But since you are stuck, this should work just as well:

```
public static bool ContainsAlpha(string s)
{
    if (s == null) return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        if (Char.IsLetter(s, i))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
public static bool ContainsAlpha(string s)
{
    if (s == null) return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        if (Char.IsLetter(s[i]))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: If I could use LINQ, maybe, but I'm stuck in .NET 1.1 with this project.

Comment: Updated to reflect that.  Good luck, brave soul!

Comment: I get, "No overload for method 'IsLetter' takes '2' arguments"

Comment: According to [these docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zff1at55(v=vs.80).aspx), it should be there.  At the bottom it says it was supported from .Net 1.0 up.

Comment: Perhaps .NET 1.0, but not CE; I'll add that to the tags.

Comment: Ahh.. I had no idea you were on WinCE.  That makes a world of difference.  See the alternate form in my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Is "FormatString" a wrong-headed name for this class, or what?

In my opinion, yes.
It should be named like `StringUtils` or `StringHelper` or something like that.
And also it should be `static`.

**Update**
What's more, I'd prefer it to be an extension method. Then it would be like:

```
string UPCE = // whatever
if(UPCE.ContainsAlpha())
{
 // ...
}
```

Comment: @MirroredFate, not sure regarding `validator`, to be honest. Because usually [validator does Validation](http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4119/4885545985_c55093102d_z.jpg), I mean it tells whether things are Ok or not, which is not quite the case here.

Comment: I agree that it's not perfect, but as a container of static methods it **would** be validating *something*, even if that was just that the passed-in string has alphabetic characters. `StringUtils` is just so broad and `StringHelper` has the same problem, in addition to sounding childish (not that sounding childish should be immediate disqualification).

Comment: I agree that `*Utils` and `*Helper` is broad, I don't like names like this too.

Comment: Though I can't agree that `to validate` is better term here. I'd say the `StringChecker` could be used, but ... Let's say, it heavily depends on the context,  without it any name is more or less the same (lu|su)cky. And we don't have the context here.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that FormatString is initialized from some form of configuration. I would check the constructor. That is the only way this makes sense (to me).

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's clearly weird (shouldn't "contains..." return a boolean?) and counter-intuitive (I have created an "empty" `FormatString`, i.e. nothing passed through its constructor, why should it do anything?), it doesn't strike me as entirely nonsensical.

"containsAlpha" might as well mean: Check if parameter 1 (`UPCE` in this case) contains alphabetic (probably alphanumeric) characters. So `FormatString` would be some generic class that checks for basic characteristics of how strings are formatted, i.e. do they contain numbers, letters, special chars etc.

It's also possible that `FormatString` is some specialized class (check the namespace?) that checks for the format of, e.g. [UPCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code), and would probably better be called `UPCFormat`, `UPCFormatVerifier` etc.

If I'm not completely mistaken, I don't recognize this as a .NET framework function. Which target framework version is this? Do you have the source of `FormatString`? What does it say?

Anyway, a beautiful piece of strange code. ;-)

Ziffusion's answer also makes sense, look at the construcor code. Perhaps it does more than it should, some initialization either in regard to some default state, or, even worse, something involving static global state stuff, which you never find out unless you run the whole system.

Edit: Now read your edit - as it turns out, I was right that `FormatString` does "generic string format checking." Probably `StringFormat` would be a slightly better name, but all in all I'd say: If you want to check the format of UPCs, have either an UPC class with a static factory/builder method which builds an UPC object from a string, including format checks, or create a `UPCFormatCheck` class which solely does the job of checking specific formats. This way, you avoid all too generic names that could mean anything. (In that class you can obviously use some cool LINQ-oneliner to do the actual check, as suggested.)

Comment: .NET 1.1 - that's what I thought it was just some obsolete/deprecated thing. I should have known - the naming conventions used by the previous programmers make Dr. Seuss seem staid and conventional by comparison.

Comment: Oh. Then you're really stuck with introducting `StringUtils` or something with a static helper method.